# Is it possible to lock a repository on Bitbucket?

Tags: git, bitbucket

**Background**

I have about 21 private repositories with maven projects in. these projects are connected to a Jenkins server. Each project has a max of 8 scripts in it to stop it taking excessive amounts of time for testing each area.

**Problem**

When someone finishes a script they upload to the correct bitbucket repository but the problem is that some of the people on the team can be careless when it comes to uploading and will upload into repositories that already have large amounts of scripts in them.

**Question**

Is it possible for me to just lock up a repository so no more commits can be made by careless people, I would like to minimise this because its a pain to revert and then have to rebuild the Jenkins project.

Comment: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/use-and-administer-repositories/administer-a-repository/repository-privacy-permissions-and-more Just give write permission  to trust people and read for others

Comment: The team uses ssh and just 1 account.

Comment: @JoeLloyd, giving each user their own account and using the Bitbucket permission system is likely the best solution.

Comment: If the shared account is the owner account, create an other account and transfert the repository

Comment: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/use-and-administer-repositories/administer-a-repository/repository-privacy-permissions-and-more

Comment: really? can i just set the entire repo to read only for all?

Comment: Seems like it is impossible at the moment. I guess you don't want to lock that user from all repositories, so it will have write permissions in the group level, which will result i write permissions to that repo. Please see https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BSERV-4157?focusedCommentId=548449&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-548449

Comment: @TomerShetah Hi. Asked this question 5 years ago, thanks for the link. I think this question just shows that I didn't understand how git should be used.

Answer (score 0):

Using Bitbucket 7.9.1 as a reference:

There are several approaches to prevent your integration branch, typically `master`, from being edited on a whim.

These settings are applied using repository settings, typically located on the left margin of the repository webpage on the bitbucket server:
[image]

Firstly, I would recommend requiring pull requests.  This can be done from the branch permissions tab in repository settings by clicking Add Permissions:
[image]

Prevent changes without a pull request by checking the related checkbox.  Pull requests ensure that changes will not be merged to your integration branch without first being reviewed and approved by the project owner or other authorized persons.  Required reviewers can be configured using the Default Reviewers tab on the left.

Additionally, user access can be more generally restricted on the Repository permissions page, where users are assigned either read, write or admin access to the repository.  Anyone with read access will be able to clone and fetch but will be restricted from pushing to the repository.  Anyone with write access will be able to clone, fetch, push, etc, but will not be able to change repository settings from the Bitbucket webpage.  Anyone with admin access will be able to change repository settings as well as being able to clone, fetch, push, etc.